# ASP.NET Website Targeted to Framework 3.5 compiling to Framework 4.0 Temporary ASP.NET files

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

When I build and run my website, which is targeted at .NET framework 3.5, from Visual Studio on my local machine, the build files are going into Temporary ASP.NET files under the 4.0 Framework folder and then the website isn't loading at all. I don't remember ever having this issue before I installed 4.0 Framework but it's been a while since I visited the existing app. Hopefully there is a perfectly logical explanation and solution. Here is my setup.

1. IIS on Windows 7 with all .NET frameworks up to .NET 4.0
2. Website project and class libraries all targeted at 3.5
3. Host file configuration with debug.website.com pointing to 127.0.0.1
4. IIS website debug.website.com with 2.0 app pool pointing to the code folder.
5. Website start properties pointing to custom debug.website.com start page /
6. Website uses IIS Rewrite Module and Forms Authentication with cookies.

Interesting point of note: If I go straight to Internet Explorer and type in debug.website.com, having first deleted all temporary ASP.NET files and completely cleared browsing history, the website compiles, files go into the 2.0 Framework temporary ASP.NET files folder and it works. If I then close out of IE, with "Delete Browsing History on Exit" unchecked, and go back into IE the website doesn't load.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

This gets stranger. I unregistered Framework 4.0 using aspnet_regiis -u, removed all temporary ASP.NET files from 2.0 folder, cleared entire browsing history from both IE and Chrome browsers and then did following.

1. Went directly to URL in Chrome - Site compiled to 2.0 folder and works.
2. Tried to open URL in IE - Site just hanging.
3. Tried to launch from Visual Studio going directly to URL- Site just hanging.

I really hope there is some simple explanation as to what could be happening here.